# How to get selected option value into PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have some dropdown list and I need to get selected option value to PHP variable. I have ajax and PHP code on same .php page

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    echo $_POST['data'];
    $var = $_POST['data'];
    exit;
}
?>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<select id="_city">
    <option value="1">
        Kharkiv
    </option>
    <option value="2">
        Lviv
    </option>
    <option value="3">
        Kiev
    </option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#_city").bind("change", function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#_city").val()
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Firebug say that I post a value and in answer I obtain a full html page, but in PHP I have nothing.

Comment: where is your form code put that also thanks

Comment: oh i forget  say that i have not form, ajax runs on change event

Comment: because there is no `data` key in your `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST)) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo $_POST['data'];
    $var = $_POST['data'];
    exit;
}
?>
<select id="_city">
    <option value="1">
        Kharkiv
    </option>
    <option value="2">
        Lviv
    </option>
    <option value="3">
        Kiev
    </option>
</select>
<script>    

    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#_city").bind("change", function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { data: $("#_city").val() }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: if (isset($_POST['data'])) doesn't runs

Comment: as you are posting data by ajax so when ever there is a post (here your ajax call) request your will get response written in `if (isset($_POST['data'])) { ...  }` section

Comment: And when you hit url directly you will see `else` part.

Comment: write `if (isset($_POST)) {.. }`

Comment: when i change value in select if condition doesnt run, i dont understand why?

Comment: if (isset($_POST)) {
print_r($_POST); return Array ( ) for me